# React render html script tag with absolute path

Tags: reactjs

I am using react to render some JS to a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src={props.file_js} />
```

it renders using relative paths:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js">
```

which breaks my URI routing policies. How can I configure react to make this link absolute? IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file.js">
```

Comment: May be like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src={"/"+props.file_js} />`

Comment: @oklas heyo! thanks!

Comment: Cars, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src={"/"+props.file_js} />
```

---

Also consider to use [html plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) for webpack with some templating.

And also looks like you want to solve code splitting task. If so, read about advanced webpack based technique [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/).